# No model named torch

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch

Dear fellow humans and others,

i have a question about using and importing pytorch into my editor.

I installed pytorch through Conda and in my terminal editor I can use pytorch,[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9k2g.jpg)
 but not in Visual studio code or Pycharm!
**No model named torch** [error code in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrmSt.jpg)

Why is that?
Very sorry for the basic question and thank you for sparing some time!
**Should I use pip?**

Comment: you should directly ask question, it will be helpful if you can directly add the output in your question instead of adding image.

Comment: @calvin -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason: The environment where the module "`torch`" is stored is not the environment you currently select in VSCode.

For installing and using the module "`torch`" in VSCode, you could refer to the following:

1. Check the environment. The Python environment displayed in the lower left corner of VSCode is the same as that of the terminal.

   [image]
2. Install the module. (`pip install torch`)
3. Run.

   [image]
4. Check the installation of the module. (`pip show torch`)

   [image]

Reference: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 1):

First, find out your python's path by writing `which python` and then [visit this page.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter) You will change the project interpreter as the conda's python path. I recommend you to stick with pip but its your call, of course.